# Microphone UDP live audio streaming

Tags: java, udp, audio-streaming, vlc

I'm trying write a java program to send live microphone data over UDP, then receive the data in VLC. I'm basically using the same code as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083342/how-to-send-audio-stream-via-udp-in-java) to package up the stream and send them over. When I receive the data in VLC, I get nothing. I see a bunch of input coming in but none of it is interpreted as audio data. It tries to resolve the information as mpga or mpgv, but I'm pretty sure it's being sent as raw audio. Is the problem on VLC's end? Should I configure VLC to receive a specific format? Or is the problem with my program not packaging the data in a way VLC can interpret it?

Comment: I don't know if this will help, I've found this though: http://grack.com/downloads/school/enel619.10/report/java_media_framework.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is capture the live microphone data to a file and figure out exactly what format it is.  Then transfer the file to VLC (if that makes sense) to see if VLC can cope with it in that form.

If you are going to use UDP in the long term, you need to be sure that the audio format you are using can cope with the loss of chunks of data in the middle of the audio stream due to network packet loss.  If not, you should use TCP rather than UDP.